# Solving PDE using finite differences

Tags: matlab, pde

I am trying to solve a coupled PDE for a thermal runaway reaction using finite difference method.  I have 2 variables, temperature (T) and concentration (Cbulk) that vary as a function of time (t) and distance (x).  I have already solved this PDE for one variable (T) while keeping Cbulk constant.

However, when I try to solve the equation with both temperature and concentration as the variables, I am getting an irrational answer.  I have attached a plot of temperature vs x when solving for both temp and concentration.  Can anyone please suggest what I can do to correct this ?  The actual answer should be a smooth temperature and concentration curve.

Please also see my MATLAB code

```
% fd_rhs.m 
function ydot=fd_rhs(time,y) 
global nt R delH E A rho cp h k delr Cbulk s

T = y(1:2:2*nt);
c = y(2:2:2*nt);


for i=1:nt-1
if i == 1
       dT(i) = k/(rho*cp*4.184*1000)*2*(s+1)*(T(i+1)-   
       T(i))/(delr*delr)+delH*A*exp(-E*1000./(R*T(i)))*c(i)/(rho*cp*1000);
       dc(i)= -A*exp(-E*1000./(R*T(i)))*c(i);
else 
dT(i) = k/(rho*cp*4.184*1000)*((T(i+1)-2*T(i) +T(i-1))/(delr*delr))+(s/R)* 
        (T(i+1)-T(i-1))/(delr*delr)+delH*A*exp(- 
        E*1000./(R*T(i)))*Cbulk/(rho*cp*1000); 
dc(i)= -A*exp(-E*1000./(R*T(i)))*c(i); 
end 
end

dT(nt)= (k/delr)/(h+(k/delr))*(k/(rho*cp*4.184*1000)*((T(nt)-2*T(nt-1) 
        +T(nt-2))/(delr*delr)))+(s/R)*(T(nt)-T(nt-1))/(delr*delr);
dc(nt)= -A*exp(-E*1000./(R*T(i)))*c(nt); 
ydot = [dT';dc']
end
```

[image: Temp vs distance]
[image: Concentration vs distance]

Thank you

Comment: This may be a better fit on the computational science SE.

Comment: Seems like you have some sort of instability going on. Without diving too deep, one suggestion is to try reducing the time step size, if you are using your own time integrator. You should post this on the Computational Science SE, and make sure to write out the coupled equations you are trying to solve. It's hard to decipher the equations by looking at the code.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Have posted a revised question in the Computational Science SE page.